# Doctrine persist without set associations

Tags: doctrine-orm, laravel-5

So, I'm using doctrine in laravel and I have a mapped class (Item) that I create a property to another entity (Product), but when I persist there is no need that I set Product in Item because I have a property with de id, but cause 'NOT NULL' database error.

Product:

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="PRODUCT")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CD_PRODUCT", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $cdProduct;
}
```

Item

```
/**
* Item
*
* @ORM\Table(name="ITEM")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Item
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="CD_PRODUCT", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
    */
    private $cdProduct;
    /**
    * @var DcB2bMercadoria
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Models\Product")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CD_PRODUCT", referencedColumnName="CD_PRODUCT")
    * })
    */
    private $product;

    public function __construct($cdProduct)
    {
        $this->cdProduct = $cdProduct;
    }
}
```

In my controller i do this:

```
$item = new Item(1);
$em->persist($item);
$em->flush();
```

But this causes NOT NULL error.

Can you guys help me?

Tks!

PS.: I simulate the classes

Answer (score 0):

How did you generated the sql schema ?

If you use `doctrine:schema:create` it should output the sql without the not null on that column.

Comment: I can't because my db is manage by a dba and he don't allow fields with null. Anyway, the value to cdProduct was be setting, but on the DQL to SQL translate they has null value. Look:
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php#L671
I do this (if is ok, i don't know, but solve my problem):
`if($newValId) {
                    $result[$owningTable][$sourceColumn] = $newValId
                        ? $newValId[$targetClass->getFieldForColumn($targetColumn)]
                        : null;
                }`